# Android - Star Rating Bar

Tags: android, image, rating

I am using badoo Star Bar, and I have it all set up and working expect for when the method `public void onFinalRating(int rating, boolean swipe) {` is called, the number of stars that I have selected doesn't stay highlighted, it goes back to the default state. Here is the repo on git hub https://github.com/badoo/StarBar

And my set up is exactly the same, haven't changed anything but here it is anyways,

This is my layout

```
 <com.badoo.mobile.views.starbar.StarBar
    android:id="@+id/starBar"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
```

And then here I implement it

```
mStarBar = (StarBar)findViewById(R.id.starBar);
    mStarBar.setOnRatingSliderChangeListener(new StarBar.OnRatingSliderChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onStartRating() {
            // The user has initiated a rating by touching the StarBar. This call will
            // immediately followed by a call to onPendingRating with the initial rating
            // value.
            Toast.makeText(DiningDetailActivity.this, "Started rating", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onPendingRating(int rating) {
            // This method will first be called when the user initiates a rating and then
            // subsequently as the rating is updated (by the user swiping his finger along
            // the bar).
            Log.i(TAG, Integer.toString(rating) + "");
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinalRating(int rating, boolean swipe) {
            // If the rating is completed successfully onFinalRating is called with the
            // final result. The swipe parameter specifies if the rating was done using
            // a tap (false) or a swipe (true).
            Toast.makeText(DiningDetailActivity.this, "Final rating " + rating, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelRating() {
            // Called if the user cancels the rating by swiping away from the StarBar and releasing.
        }
    });
```

So my question is how when I select lets say 4 stars to get them to say highlighted, instead of going back to the gray state?

I have looked at the readME file and gone over his code and can't seem to find it.

Thanks so much for the help :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to save the ratings. You only show toasts. I dont know the methods of the library but there is probably a method for changing the active stars.

Comment: right but I can't see a method that saves the stars... would you mind taking a quick look at the library

Comment: Saving data is easy and you can do it on your own :) you can use sqlite databases or json objects :)

Comment: its not about saving the value, its about have the stars be highlighted?

Comment: I think you missed the oncheckedchanged method. I looked up the sample code on github and there is a oncheckedchangelistener and a oncheckedchanged method. Demo: https://github.com/badoo/StarBar/blob/master/sample/src/com/badoo/mobile/views/starbar/demo/MainActivity.java

Comment: The onCheckChanged method and listener does not set the number of stars highlighted

Comment: I try to implement `implements StarBar.OnRatingSliderChangeListener` but I get compile error `must be declared abstract or implement onPendingRating(int)`

Comment: kk great whenever you get around to it